# how to clear ajax response before create modal open

Tags: php, jquery

This is the form modal code ...

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add Ajax</button>
```

Here I can able to add/edit my form. But, the problem is when I click the **Add Ajax** to create a new form after the click edit button it contains the last edited modal data. I can't reset the data ... modal is only empty after page refresh

**script tag**

```
$(".edit-ajax").click(function() {
let id =$(this).data('id');
$("#myModal").find('[name="id"]').val(id);

$.ajax({
url: frontend_form_object.ajaxurl,
type:'POST',
async:false, // Code paused. (Other code waiting for this to finish.)
data: {
  action: 'edit_ajax_test',
  id : id,
},
})
.done(function(response) {
console.log(response.success);

$("[name=first_name]").val(response.data.edit_ajax.caller_name);
$("[name=last_name]").val(response.data.edit_ajax.caller_state);
//toastr.success('Successfully saved', 'Success', {timeOut: 5000});

 $('#myModal').modal('hide'); 

})
});
```

Comment: What do you want exactly, you have to be a little be clearer. How does your modal looks like? Do you want to show the response of the ajax request in the modal? Should the modal show up before the request will be send? Should the modal close after a few seconds? Which form do you mean? Where are the inputs of your ajax done method?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".edit-ajax").click(function() {
   $("#myModal").find("#yourformId")[0].reset();
   //rest of your code

}
```

Comment: i tried this one but nothing happens when i click for add new form it contains the previous data